# Is Fourier Transform relation a Convolution?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, signal-processing

I was wondering if the Fourier transform relation can be viewed as evaluation in zero of the convolution between $x(t)$ and $e^{j\omega t}$, so if $*$ is the convolution operator

$$X(f) = \left.x(t) * e^{j\omega t}\right|_{t=0}$$

If I'm right will you be able to prove the Convolution Theorem for Fourier Transform with this approach ?

Comment: You could do that, it does seem to work out algebraically. I haven't given much thought to if this proves the convolution theorem.

Comment: $t = 0$, $\tau = x$ $f(\tau) = f(x)$, $g(\tau) = e^{2\pi i \chi x} , g(t - \tau) = e^{-2\pi i \chi x}$ then you can apply: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution and get the same result as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition

Comment: $(x(t)*h(t))*e^{jwt}$ it will be sufficent to proove that that serie of convolutions is equal to $(x(t)*e^{jwt}) \cdot ( h(t)*e^{jwt})$

Comment: I feel that the property $h(t) h(s) = h(t+s)$ of the exponential factor $h(t) = e^{j\omega t}$ is significant for the convolution theorem. You may be able to prove that any kernel $h$ with this property satisfies $(f*h)\cdot(g*h) = (f*g)*h$, from which the version for the Fourier transform will follow. However, that proof won't be significantly different from the standard proof of the convolution theorem.